# How set selected value on the fly Dropdown Option in Table from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How can I set default selected value on the fly?

```js
var world = '\u003cselect class=\" form-control\" id=\"world_id\" name=\"world_id\"\u003e\u003coption value=\"1\"\u003eworld\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"2\"\u003eword123\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"3\"\u003eword 2\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003c/select\u003e';

$.each(json, function (i, value) {
    a = $('#table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + world + '</td><td></tr>');
    a.find('td:eq(0)').find('select').val(value.world_id); // not work set default selected value 
});
```

example value.world_id is 3 and text world 2
my problem
the last dropdown not set value to 3 with text world 2
see result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGBhU.png
i need like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbYEe.png

Comment: As it stands, it is hard for viewers to understand what you're asking for. I have an answer ready if you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `selected` property of the `<option>` and not it's parent `<select>` tag. I'm not very familiar with jQuery so please correct me if I don't get this exactly right, but I think you want something like:

```
var world = '\u003cselect class=\" form-control\" id=\"world_id\" name=\"world_id\"\u003e\u003coption value=\"1\"\u003eworld\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"2\"\u003eword123\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"3\"\u003eword 2\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003c/select\u003e';

$.each(json, function (i, value) {
a=$('#table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + world + '</td><td></tr>');
a.find('td:eq(0)').find('[value~=' + value.world_id + ']').selected="selected"; // <--- not confident on my usage of find and .selected as I'm new to jQuery 
});
```

see [Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~=”value”]](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) for more information on the .find() usage and the selected attributes respectively